# Rest Api to get Products how to pass filter “status” and “visibility”

Tags: api, rest, magento, magento-1.9

```
$apiUrl = 'http://192.168.1.7/xxxx/api/rest';
```

...

```
$oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);

$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products?page=1&limit=5";

$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => '*/*'));
$productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());

print_r($productsList);
exit;
```

> I have getting list of product using rest api but i wants a filter
>   with **status=1** and **visibility=4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$apiUrl/products?page=1&limit=5&filter[0][attribute]=status&filter[0][eq]=1&filter[1][attribute]=visibility&filter[1][eq]=4
```

> But before trying make sure that you are allowed to view and filter by
>   status and visibility.
>
> You can set the allowed attributes from **System->Web Services->Rest
>   Attributes and select the role you are using (admin, customer or
>   guest).**

[More info for filter](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/get_filters.html)